# Updating two tables with form

Tags: ms-access-2016

I have a database with 2 tables.  Both tables have a common key FAM_NO and this field is primary key in both tables.   I have a main form with a subform that displays the data from both of these tables (with a relationship created on the primary key). However I now need to be able to create new records.   How can I create a new record using the form/subform that will update BOTH of these tables?
I added a button to the current form to "add new record", but the I get an error "You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table".   I'm more of a newbie - so any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!   Thank you.  (I'm using ms-access 2016)

Answer (score 0):

When you look at your relationship in the relationships window. double click the line representing the relationship between your 2 tables. Inside the "Edit Relationships" window you will see the names of your 2 tables. One table under "Table/Query:" and the other table under "Related Table/Query:". The table under "Table/Query" is the table that can have records in it without having related records in the second table.

With this being said, you have to insert into the first table before you can insert into the second table.

Without knowing the full coding you have behind the command button you are using, you can use something like below to accomplish this task.

```
Private sub Command0_Click() 'Change command0 to the name of your control
With currentdb
    .execute "INSERT INTO Table1 ( FAM_NO ) " & _
             "VALUES ('Whatever value/control you are using');"
    .execute "INSERT INTO Table2 ( FAM_NO ) " & _
             "VALUES ('Same Value as above');"
End With
End Sub
```

If this doesn't work, let me know and we will do more digging.